# My website load resources from another site

Tags: web

I check Google speed insight and find out that resource of other website is loaded although they are not appear in my website ? And i load the page source code but can't find any related link
 Who could explain it for me and tell me some solution, some tips to inspect and resolve the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To Fix all the problems in Google PageSpeed.

Go through [Google PageSpeed Insights Rules](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules) & Follow all the steps given in the Rules.